# Compilation error when using pound sterling as variable name

Tags: java, maven, unicode

I have the following variable in my java program - `int myVar££abc = -1;`

It compiles fine in the editor and I'm able to run and debug locally (on my Windows machine).

But when compiling on a Linux machine using Tycho, I get the following error:

```
03:01:09 [ERROR]    int myVar??abc = -1;
03:01:09 [ERROR]             ^^^^^
03:01:09 [ERROR] Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Is there a tycho configuration or file conversion I need to do to allow the pound sterling symbol to be processed correctly as a variable name?

Comment: It's allowed to take letters from the entire Unicode character set, so your identifier seems legal. The issue may come from the platform default converter, try to pass `-encoding XXX` param while compiling you code (i.e. `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...`)